# How to install doctrine extensions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-extensions

While learning Symfony2 i can't find any resources that will tell me what to do to install doctrine extensions library. i know that I should add

```
new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
```

to my AppKernel.php, but what about composer? i always use it when i install eg. DoctrineFixtures, but i dont know what exactly i need to add there in this case. I tried

```
"gedmo/doctrine-extensions" : "master-dev",
```

But `php composer.phar update` returns php FatalError:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle' not found in /path/to/my/symfony/project/app/AppKernel.php on line 20
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception
```

Comment: https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install `"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.0"` via composer if you want to use that bundle.

`gedmo/doctrine-extensions` is PHP library, not symfony bundle

When you wonder what to install, searching for a lib or bundle, just use the packagist.org

https://packagist.org/search/?q=StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle